# Recording and playing audio simultaneously with PyAudio and NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, audio, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

Currently i can record audio and save it as a NumPy array. What i need is after audio has been recorded i want to be able to record again but play this NumPy array at the same time

```
import pyaudio
import numpy

CHUNK = 1024
WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) 

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=numpy.int16))

numpydata = numpy.hstack(frames)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: If you don't insist on using PyAudio, you could use `sounddevice.rec()` and `sounddevice.playrec()`, see https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.12/usage.html#simultaneous-playback-and-recording (full disclosure: I'm the author).

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading. Go to the official documentation for more information [here](http://www.google.com/) I don't know recording and playing audio very well, so I have just created a template that should work for you.

Here is my example:

```
from threading import Thread

def record():
  #Put your recording function here
def play():
  #Put your playing function here

Thread(target = record).start()
Thread(target = play).start()   
#These two start the two functions at the same time. If you want to only run the play
#function after it runs the record function once, you could do something like this:
```

Here is the better one:

```
from threading import Thread

def record():
  #Put your recording function here
def play():
  #Put your playing function here

while recorded!=True
  Thread(target = record)
  recorded=True

Thread(target = record).start()
Thread(target = play).start()
```

To repeat the last two lines in the second example, you can just add a `while` or `for` loop. Please feel free to ask questions in the comments.